# Python: Take two strings and return only character and index that exactly match

Tags: python

I've been trying to solve this question from The Coder's Apprentice by Pieter Spronck http://www.spronck.net/pythonbook/pythonbook.pdf, page 146 via pdf, or 132 in the book itself. Here is the exact question:

> Write code that uses two strings. For each character in the first string that has
> exactly the same character at the same index in the second string, you print the character
> and the index. Watch out that you do not get an “index out of bounds” runtime error. Test
> it with the strings "The Holy Grail" and "Life of Brian".

I'm aware there is the option to use coord but it's not been covered in the book so far and I want to learn in the precise manner in which the books presents the tools available so that I can really get on top of the fundamentals.

I can find the matching the characters and their corresponding indexes, but I'm at a loss as to how I return only the characters and indexes that exactly match. I've tried quite a few different ideas but I just can't seem to crack it. I've only presented the code that returned the matching characters and their index, not any of the things I tried since they just returned errors

Thanks:

```
def two_string(a, b):
    character = []
    index = []
    for i in a:
        if i in b:
            character.append(i)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] in b:
            index.append(i)
    print(character)
    print(index)

two_string('The Holy Grail', 'Life of Brian')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the restriction of only using basic functions, you could do something like this:

```
def two_string(a, b):
  for i in range(min(len(a),len(b))):
    if a[i] == b[i]:
      print(f"Match of character '{a[i]}' found at index {i}")

two_string('The Holy Grail', 'Life of Brian')
# Output: 
# Match of character 'o' found at index 5
# Match of character 'a' found at index 11
```

Comment: While using `enumerate` and `zip` is the cleaner and better option, I think this is the most appropriate answer based on the implicit level of knowledge of the OP. Simply find out which of the two strings has the shorter length to avoid IndexError and just compare the individual characters.

Comment: @Reti43 thanks, that exactly the reason why I did not use `enumerate` or `zip` :)

Comment: This is perfect, easy to understand and represents my current level, thanks!

Comment: Having said that, there's a lot of value in the other answers for future readers who don't have the same constraint as the OP.

Answer (score 6):

```
def two_string(a,b):
    for i, (ca, cb) in enumerate(zip(a,b)):
        if ca==cb:
            print(ca, i)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about some dictionary comprehension with `zip` and `enumerate`

```
def two_string(a: str, b: str) -> dict:
    return {idx: match[0] for idx, match in enumerate(zip(a.lower(),b.lower())) if match[0] == match[1]}

two_string('The Holy Grail', 'Life of Brian')

# {5: 'o', 11: 'a'}
```

Comment: Go ahead and use _more_ unpacking: `{... for idx, (c_a, c_b) in ...`

Answer (score 2):

You could probably write:

```
def two_string(a, b):
    res = []
    i = 0
    for c in a:
        if c in b and i == b.index(c):
            res.append((c,i))
        i += 1
    print(res)
```

Prints:

```
[('o', 5), ('a', 11)]
```

Answer (score 1):

One loop is sufficient:

```
def two_string(a, b):
    for i, ca in enumerate(a):
        # Prevent index out of bounds
        if i < len(b) and b[i] == ca:
            print(i, ca)


two_string('The Holy Grail', 'Life of Brian')
```

Out:

```
5 o
11 a
```

Answer (score 0):

Expression:

```
i in b
```

returns True if there is character i in string regardles of the position
also you used 2 for loops but only one is nessery

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of people wouldn't find this idiomatic :)

```py
from itertools import count
from operator import eq, itemgetter
from typing import Iterable, Tuple
def two_string(a: str, b: str) -> Iterable[Tuple[str, int]]:
    return map(itemgetter(1),
               filter(itemgetter(0),
                      zip(map(eq, a, b),
                          zip(a, count()))))
```

```
$> for tup in two_string('The Holy Grail', 'Life of Brian'):
--   print(tup)
-- 
('o', 5)
('a', 11)
```